# SQL - Custom Date Groups

Tags: mysql, sql, date

really hitting my head on a wall with this one.

I'm basically trying to create week/month groups within SQL, so say a team member started their contract on 05/01/2021, then 05/01/2021 - 12/01/2021 would be week 1, 12/01/2021 - 19/01/2021 would be week 2 etc up until week 26. The purpose is so I can then use these week groups to more easily make comparisons to other team members.

As an example, say I have simple data like this laid out.

| Staff_Members | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| team Member 1 | 25/06/2019 |
| team Member 2 | 30/06/2019 |

I want to turn it into this in SQL.

| Staff_Members | Start Date | Week Group | Week Start | Week End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 1 | 25/06/2019 | 02/07/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 2 | 02/07/2019 | 09/07/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 3 | 09/07/2019 | 16/07/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 4 | 16/07/2019 | 23/07/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 5 | 23/07/2019 | 30/07/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 6 | 30/07/2019 | 06/08/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 7 | 06/08/2019 | 13/08/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 8 | 13/08/2019 | 20/08/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 9 | 20/08/2019 | 27/08/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 10 | 27/08/2019 | 03/09/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 11 | 03/09/2019 | 10/09/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 12 | 10/09/2019 | 17/09/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 13 | 17/09/2019 | 24/09/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 14 | 24/09/2019 | 01/10/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 15 | 01/10/2019 | 08/10/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 16 | 08/10/2019 | 15/10/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 17 | 15/10/2019 | 22/10/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 18 | 22/10/2019 | 29/10/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 19 | 29/10/2019 | 05/11/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 20 | 05/11/2019 | 12/11/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 21 | 12/11/2019 | 19/11/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 22 | 19/11/2019 | 26/11/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 23 | 26/11/2019 | 03/12/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 24 | 03/12/2019 | 10/12/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 25 | 10/12/2019 | 17/12/2019 |
| Team member 1 | 25/06/2019 | Week 26 | 17/12/2019 | 24/12/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 1 | 30/06/2019 | 07/07/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 2 | 07/07/2019 | 14/07/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 3 | 14/07/2019 | 21/07/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 4 | 21/07/2019 | 28/07/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 5 | 28/07/2019 | 04/08/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 6 | 04/08/2019 | 11/08/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 7 | 11/08/2019 | 18/08/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 8 | 18/08/2019 | 25/08/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 9 | 25/08/2019 | 01/09/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 10 | 01/09/2019 | 08/09/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 11 | 08/09/2019 | 15/09/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 12 | 15/09/2019 | 22/09/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 13 | 22/09/2019 | 29/09/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 14 | 29/09/2019 | 06/10/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 15 | 06/10/2019 | 13/10/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 16 | 13/10/2019 | 20/10/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 17 | 20/10/2019 | 27/10/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 18 | 27/10/2019 | 03/11/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 19 | 03/11/2019 | 10/11/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 20 | 10/11/2019 | 17/11/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 21 | 17/11/2019 | 24/11/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 22 | 24/11/2019 | 01/12/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 23 | 01/12/2019 | 08/12/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 24 | 08/12/2019 | 15/12/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 25 | 15/12/2019 | 22/12/2019 |
| Team member 2 | 30/06/2019 | Week 26 | 22/12/2019 | 29/12/2019 |

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.
Tom

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: That said, issues of data display are generally best resolved in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select staff_member, start_date, 1 as week_number, start_date as week_start, start_date + interval 7 day as end_date
      from t
      union all
      select staff_member, start_date, week_number + 1, end_date, end_date + interval 7 day
      from cte
      where year(start_date) = year(week_start)
     )
 select *
 from cte
 order by staff_member, week_start;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d8f06d1f31f6396f85e5bec44b212bc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for this! Hadn't heard of recursive CTE until now, so this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

use dateadd(day, 7 , "start-date")
it adds 7 days to your start date and give you end date.